# HTML5 canvas, AngularJS, After rotating image not able to move

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

I am using this library to upload and crop the images
http://andyshora.com/angular-image-cropper.html.

I have added functions for rotate left, rotate right, flip horizontal and flip vertical to overcome mobile EXIF orientation issues.

```
scope.clockwise = function() { 
                            scope.angleInDegrees+=90;
                                drawRotated(scope.angleInDegrees);
                        };

                        scope.counterclockwise = function() { 
                                scope.angleInDegrees-=90;
                                drawRotated(scope.angleInDegrees);    
                        };


                        function drawRotated(degrees){

                            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
                            ctx.save();
                            ctx.translate(canvasWidth/2,canvasHeight/2);
                            ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
                            transformPoint = untransformPoint = function(x, y) {
                                            return {
                                                x: x,
                                                y: y
                                            };
                                        };
                            ctx.drawImage($img,-$img.width/2,-$img.width/2);
                            ctx.restore();



                        }
```

After rotate I can not move the image with rotated image. While clicking image its automatically displaying first uploaded image(ie before rotation).

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/x9f94yz5/1/ (Not a running code)

Comment: Do you save the user's actions so that they're repeated each time you re-draw the canvas?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Niddro. Sorry I am very new to HTML5 and AngularJS. What do you mean by user action save.

Comment: If the user clicks whatever you have that would make the image appear rotated, you need to repeat that each time the canvas is re-drawn. The rotation you do in the code, does not permanently rotate the image, only for that time it's drawn.

Comment: @Niddro, Could you please explain me how to make that as permanent. As you said it will solve my problem I guess

Comment: I would make a variable that stores the current rotation of the image `var total_rotation = 0` (the rotation at the start is 0, of course). If the code where you draw the image (you should only have one of those) you'll add the rotation. When a user chooses to rotate the image, change the new variable and then repaint the image. Here's a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/kLedcLzu/  on row 16, u can manually change the total_rotation. In your code, you'd have a function change that variable as a result of the user's actions.

Comment: Thanks @Niddro, I have tried to use solution but seems like i facing CPU usage problem while uploading larger size images.